# Use OpenWeather Icons as Markers on Leaflet Map

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet, maps, markers

I'm trying to add the weather icons returned from an openweather API call to my leaflet map as markers but not getting any luck.

They will display in a pop up on the marker in an  tag and when I console.log the iconUrl the link appears to the correct icon but they will only display as the default blue marker on the map - any ideas?

Relevant parts of my script:

````
var weatherMarker = L.markerClusterGroup();

(Inside Ajax Call success function):

if (result.status.name == "ok") {
                                        
    var temperature = Math.round(result.data[1].temp);
                                            
    var weatherIcon = L.icon({
     iconUrl: "http://openweathermap.org/img/w/" + result.data[1].icon + ".png",
     iconSize: [25, 30],
     iconAnchor: [22, 94],
     popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
                                });
                                            
weatherMarker.addLayer(new L.marker([lat, lng], {iconUrl: weatherIcon, crossOrigin: true})).bindPopup(temperature + " &deg;C " + result.data[1].weather).addTo(mymap);
                                        
                                        
        ```

[![Appearance of Marker on the map][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1xgA.png
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the option `icon` instead `iconUrl`:

```
weatherMarker.addLayer(new L.marker([lat, lng], {icon: weatherIcon, crossOrigin: true})).bindPopup(temperature + " &deg;C " + result.data[1].weather).addTo(mymap);
```